# Wordpress: Output a custom post type list by two Custom Taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, list, custom-post-type, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I need to list out a custom post type organised by two different taxonomies that are on these posts.

I have a custom post type of properties/apartments with taxonomies of location and type/size I am trying to list them out like the below

Required Layout

[image: Required Layout[1]]

**Custom Post Type**

**Apartment Location**

Apartment Size 1

1. List item 1
2. List item 2
3. List item 3

Apartment Size 2

1. List item 4
2. List item 5
3. List item 6

**Apartment Location 2**

Apartment Size 1

1. List item 7
2. List item 8
3. List item 9

Apartment Size 2

1. List item 10
2. List item 11
3. List item 12

I'm Using the current code but it's just spitting out everything under each taxonomy size? And i cant get it to filter by Location and then Size

```
          <?php
      $terms = get_terms('apartment_location');
      foreach( $terms as $term ):
      ?>
      <h2><?php echo $term->name;?></h2>
      <?php
      $posts = get_posts(array(
          'post_type' => 'apartments',
          'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
          'term' => $term->slug,
          'nopaging' => true
      )); ?>
                    <?php
                    $terms = get_terms('apartment_type');
                    foreach( $terms as $term ):
                    ?>
                      <h3><?php echo $term->name;?></h3>
                      <?php
                      $posts = get_posts(array(
                          'post_type' => 'apartments',
                          'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
                          'term' => $term->slug,
                          'nopaging' => true
                      )); ?>
                      <?php foreach($posts as $post): setup_postdata($post); ?>
                              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br>
                              <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
                      <?php endforeach; ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```